# перегрузка оператора деления

Tags: c#

как реализовать перегрузку оператора деления (частного). Если можно пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это должно сработать:

```
class Counter
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public static Counter operator /(Counter c1, Counter c2)
    {
        return new Counter { Value = c1.Value / c2.Value };
    }
}
```

Comment: return new Counter { Value = c1.Value + c2.Value }; Не понимаю почему операция сочетания в скобках

Comment: Denys, Спасибо, исправил. Наверное, задумался о чем-то :)

Comment: Это как раз показательный пример, почему перегрузка операторов некоторыми теоретиками считается вредной: нельзя сразу сказать, что именно делает оператор. Вроде как деление, а на самом деле за ним может быть что угодно. PS: я думал, что это намеренно так сделано.